# Launching InstallSield 2010 deployed Installer in a simple user account

Tags: installation, installshield, setup-deployment, admin-rights

I'm using Installshield 2010 to deploy my winforms project, when installing the setup.exe on an Administrator account i didn't got any problem, however when i tried to install it on a simple user account i got a message saying that i must login as Administrator to perform the install process. I've noticed that if if I make the combination "Shift + Right Click" on my setup.exe i got a new option in my context menu, it's "Run as an other user", when selecting this action i got a prompt of login and password, i entered then my Administrator login and password and the install is performed successfully !

My question is :

Are there any configuration or action that i can do in Installshield, which simulate "Run as an other user" automatically to allow me to enter Administrator Login and Password ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't need to actually run the setup exe and the MSI is marked as requiring elevation, then Windows will ask for credentials during the install, the "over the shoulder" install. For MSIs there is also this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369519(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try set the [execution level in the manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384691.aspx) of the setup package to "Require Administrator". This will trigger the UAC prompt the moment you launch the installer, from that prompt you should be able to enter your credentials.

I don't know exactly where installshield has this option, but surely it can be configured, its a standard for all packaging tools.

Comment: Thanks, this is the trick. FYI we can find the option within InstallShield in "Releases" => tab Setup.exe => Required Execution Level, this should be set to "Administrator"